# I want to store customer shipment and billing address should I do in one table on two?

Tags: database-design

When a customer orders a product he can give a different billing address and a different shipping address how should this be implemented using good schema techniques, what are the recommended best practices for this? thanks

Answer (score 11):

Have two tables:

- an `Orders` table
- an `Address` table

On the `Orders` table, you should have two foreign key references to `ShipmentAddress` and `BillingAddress`, both referencing the `Address` table.

I would definitely put those two addresses into the same table - each "thing" of the same type (address) belongs in the same table.

Comment: +1 thanks, it made me think before creating my nth DB design mess.

Answer (score 0):

there should be different table for all the entities .
1. Customer
2.Products
3.Order

in order table u can user the address field to store the shipping address and billing address